# String match using values in one worksheet with long list (52K) of values from a column in another worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

In worksheet 1: I have a fairly short list (~75) of values (text strings) and would like to find all matches of these strings with values from a column in another worksheet (worksheet 2)... these values might exist anywhere within a much longer string/passage in that known column.

Further,  I'd like to be able generate a third worksheet with rows equal to the matched values... building a row for each, but also containing some of the other columns from worksheet 2.

Worksheet 1

```
ABC
DEF
GHI
...
XYZ
```

Worksheet 2

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
blah1   blahA   Chemical DEF is a compound
blah2   blahB   Compound 24231 (also known as GHI)...
```

Worksheet 3

```
Col1  Col2    Col3
DEF   blah1   blahA
GHI   blah2   blahB
```

Can this be done with Excel?

Comment: You can do it, but using a database with indexes is probably a more efficient method.  What have you tried?

Comment: Thank you for the fast response.  Just starting. I am not, obviously, a big Excel user.  So I am looking at MATCH, and LOOKUP. Just poking around trying to understand where to start, try out.

Comment: This may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8313919/657668

Answer (score 0):

First, this will definitely take some time to be done on an excel sheet with 52k lines, and since the column containing the passage in Worksheet 2 is after the things you want in Worksheet 3, I think that using `MATCH()` is better.

In Worksheet 3, copy and paste the text strings you're looking for in Worksheet 2. You will then remove the ones not found with a filter later on (in this case, you will remove `ABC` and `XYZ` later on).

In column 2 of Worksheet 3, use the formula (this assumes you're using headers which are in the first row in every sheet, otherwise, change `A2` to `A1`):

```
=INDEX('Worksheet 2'!A:B,MATCH("*"&'Worksheet 3'!A2&"*",'Worksheet 2'!C:C,0),1)
```

And in column 3 of Worksheet 3, use the formula:

```
=INDEX('Worksheet 2'!A:B,MATCH("*"&'Worksheet 3'!A2&"*",'Worksheet 2'!C:C,0),2)
```

Drag those two formulas to the end of the list and wait until the calculations are done. After that, copy the data and paste as values (Paste Special > Paste Values. This will speed things up onwards) and apply a filter so you can remove all the `#N/A`, if any, from the table. Sort your table to remove spaces in between rows.

Comment: Excellent.  Many thanks.  Will work on this today.  Thanks again.